# How to convert long number value as number only ans not scientific form during fast cluster process in Sas

Tags: sas

I am running fast cluster process in Sas.
The frequency value i get is in Scientific form in excel output i get. I dont want it. What part of code I should change. Attached below is the snipeet of my code and the output I am getting

```
%MACRO LOOP(Start,End);

%DO MAXC=&Start %TO &End;
    ODS HTML PATH="J:\DIAC-CITI\Client_Data\CARDS\03 Analysis\Clustering\Pre-Optimization\Output\Cluster Outputs"
    BODY="MaxCluster&MAXC..xls"
    STYLE=DEFAULT;
    ODS LISTING CLOSE;
    OPTIONS NOLABEL;
    PROC FASTCLUS
        DATA=Pre_Modeling
        OUT=test
        MAXCLUSTERS=&MAXC
        MAXITER=100;
        OUTSTAT=stat&maxc;
        FREQ FREQUENCY;
        WEIGHT REGIONAL_WTS;
        VAR RISK_SCORE;
        TITLE ' ';
    RUN;
    ODS HTML CLOSE;
    ODS LISTING;

    data stat&maxc;
    set stat&maxc(rename=( _type_=type));
    where type in('RSQ','PSEUDO_F','CCC');
    run;

    proc sort data=stat&maxc;
    by type;
    run;

    proc transpose data=stat&maxc out=stat&maxc prefix=value&maxc.;
    by type;
    var over_all;
    run;

%END;
%MEND LOOP;
%LOOP(1,30)
```

Output

```
Cluster Frequency


1   69
2   2295564
4   172098
6   6
9   6941
12  32
18  872126
8   4.56E+07
16  34347
17  1.98E+07
15  9568079
10  8824842
7   9669026
3   5855012
5   3353213
11  876159
13  313310
14  202065
19  33736
```

The frequency I am getting is in scientific form. I dont want that.If I change it to number in excel, it gets rounded off and the original number gets lost.

Can anyone help me

When I added format to the code

```
PROC FASTCLUS
        DATA=Pre_Modeling
        OUT=test
        MAXCLUSTERS=22
        MAXITER=100
        OUTSTAT=stat22;
        FREQ frequency format best16. ;
        WEIGHT REGIONAL_WTS;
        VAR RISK_SCORE;
        TITLE ' ';
    RUN;

PROC FASTCLUS
        DATA=Pre_Modeling
        OUT=test
        MAXCLUSTERS=22
        MAXITER=100
        OUTSTAT=stat22;
        FREQ format frequency best16.  ;
        WEIGHT REGIONAL_WTS;
        VAR RISK_SCORE;
        TITLE ' ';
    RUN;
```

Both the codes did not run and it gave an error.

Comment: SAS use  scientific notation to show numeric values, if you don't like, you could use format, such as  format frequency best16. to show all digits.

Answer (score 0):

Format statement should be put in the last section of your code: Proc Transpose.

```
   proc transpose data=stat&maxc out=stat&maxc prefix=value&maxc.;
    by type;
    var over_all;
    format over_all best16.;
    run;
```